# Edit a .jar file in linux

Tags: java, linux, vim, centos

I have a jar file and I use `vim` to view my JAR contents, everything look fine. But when I move my jar and also some important file to my friends pc which is run in centos,the contents jar file not readable which look similar to this !

```
ð<91>H¶<88>²Ò^S$ß^M<92>Ç^D®R<88>k´NÐ|^]<83>¸aXnâ<96>Á&q^[ãF^N½^^s^F^?^@PK^C^D
^@^@^@^H^@<8f>VJJßê¥=s^B^@^@^?^D^@^@%^@^@^@rh/com/app/writer/AgingWriter$2.class<85>S^?O^SA^P}^K¥G<8f>^Sj^Q+*òCÔR<94>EDEÀ*6<90><90><9c>b^B^AÿÝ^^×öàzÛÜmE?<96>$bâ^_~^@?<94>qv<8b>P!@/Ý<9d>};;óæÍîï??^?^A<98>G9^C^[^S6úp¿^W<93>6^^àa^FcxÔ<8b><82><8d>)^T3<98>Æc^[O0c<81>[<98>µð<94>!­êA29Ë0êÆuîÉ^F^WÍ&?<88>^CåÇ|¥^VDµ^]c/<91>ër^P^EªÄ0Q¸Âwj<9b>!U<96>»>Ã<80>^[Dþ<87>V£âÇ[¢^R^R<92>s¥'Âm^Q^Gz}^L¦4^M^Fg=<8a>ü¸^\<8a>$ñi9~y<9e>É9bÕgð5)
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: Don't open a `jar` with `vim`, it's a zip file. Use `zip` (or `jar`).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What did you mean by use zip or jar ?

Comment: You can use `jar xvvf TheFile.jar` (or `unzip TheFile.jar`) to extract the contents of your `jar`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks,but I want to edit the contents in jar file

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have unzipped it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How can I edit the jar file which is the xml file?

Comment: The jar file is still a special kind of zip file. You unzip it, edit the file, and the re-jar it (jar files do have meta-data). There is no way to edit an xml file (in place) in a jar file. The zip file format doesn't allow for streaming edits.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But is there a way I can read the contents ? I use `jar xvvf TheFile.jar` but it only able to see the package name. I can't select

Comment: That dumps the contents to disk. The syntax of `jar` is the same as `tar`, but use `jar -h` for help.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Do you know why I can edit the jar file using vim in my  pc but cannot in my friend pc?

Comment: You must have some kind of vim plugin package, I don't usually run redhat derivatives (anymore, `yum` might be able to help). Good luck.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yum really helped. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install emacs

```
yum install emacs
```

Then use below command to read the content

```
emacs somejar.jar
```

select the content and press `Enter`

To save and quit from the editor, press C-x C-s (Ctrl+x, followed by Ctrl+s).

Source :  [How To Use the Emacs Editor in Linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-emacs-editor-in-linux)

P/S : Only can edit xml file